# Working with FedEx API and .Net

Tags: .net, fedex

I am trying to get a list of rates for all available services from FedEx using 1 call, and having a tough time with their documentation. Anyone have some code snippets of how you interfaced with them? .Net code is preferable but anything will help more than their crapping code samples!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe you'll have a look over here http://fedex.com/us/solutions/shipapi/sample_code.html/
if you want to consume a webservice, visual studio makes your life easy as all you have to do is import a web reference (or service reference, as it is called with wcf) ans consume it.